# Trying to skip pre-flight OPTIONS using JS locally

Tags: javascript, html, api, cors, bartender

I'm sending a simple POST request using js fetch, it's being sent to the [Bartender Label Software Integration Application](https://www.seagullscientific.com/media/1371/bartender-integration-methods.pdf) but it's unable to handle OPTIONS or the CORS Pre flight sent when using the following code:

```
<script>
        const TurkishDelightBrownieButton = document.getElementById('Turkish Delight Brownie');
        TurkishDelightBrownieButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            fetch('http://localhost:8000/brownie', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: {
                        Allergens: 'Egg, Wheat, Soya',
                        Ingredients: "Sugar, Butter, Cream ,stuff like that",
                        Flavour: "Brownie Flavoured",
                        DatePacked: "12/08/2021",
                        BestBefore: "22/08/2021"
                    }
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response)
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                    })
        });
    </script>
```

It's all being done locally, so I'm trying to make the request appropriate for the Bartender integration - which is application/json mostly.

If anyone has any suggestions or different ways to do this, I'd love some help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you're running your frontend locally on a port other than 8000 (the port used by your backend). Therefore, the request issued by your frontend to your backend is [*cross-origin*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin). Moreover, the content type (`application/json`) specified for your request it a [*non-simple* one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests).

As a result, the browser will send a preflight request; there's no way around that.